# How to create a callback for each time a fragment is visible?

Tags: android, android-fragments, visibility

I have tried those methods:

```
@Override
public void setMenuVisibility(final boolean visible) {
   if (visible) {
       CupsTracker.instance.sendAnalyticsView(CupsTracker.VENUES_LIST_SCREEN);
   }
   super.setMenuVisibility(visible);
}

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        CupsTracker.instance.sendAnalyticsView(CupsTracker.VENUES_LIST_SCREEN);
    }
    else { CupsLog.d(TAG, "list is not visable");}
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
}

@Override
public void onHiddenChanged(boolean hidden) {
    if (!hidden) {
        CupsTracker.instance.sendAnalyticsView(CupsTracker.VENUES_LIST_SCREEN);
    }
    else { CupsLog.d(TAG, "list is not visable");}
    super.onHiddenChanged(hidden);
}
```

But for some reason non of them is getting called.
Does some one knows how this can be done? Now I'm not talking about a `ViewPager` but simple `hide` and `show` transactions.

Comment: Visible = onStart() and no longer visible = onStop()

Comment: it's not that simple, I don't think the fragment runs those methods on each hide and show. beside that some time my fragment is still intact but is covered by another fragment. So it's exists in the stack but not visible to the user.

Comment: Have you tried onResume?  It seems from the documentation that your fragment should be paused every time it is even partially covered by another fragment or activity, so I'd be interested to hear if and why it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try **onAttach**? And there you fire a listener

Comment: `onHiddenChanged` work always for ALREADY binded fragment at activity. But if you first time add fragment (FragmentTransaction::add), then onHiddenChanged don't called, but called: `onAttach`, `onStart`, `onResume`.